# Pro and cons about creating QObjects components on the stack instead of creating them dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qobject

Are there any kind of problem if I allocate QObjects on the stack to avoid problem about memory management? Should I prefer dynamic allocated QObjects and delegate memory managament by qt object trees and its ownership mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is at the very top level (in `main` when you create your inital window for example), you really shouldn't.

The basic reason is that Qt is simply not designed for automatic objects. Qt is designed around dynamic allocation and managing your memory for you, violating this can lead to some nasty results. One that immediatly springs to mind is the order of destruction for automatic objects, automatic objects are destructed in reverse order of their construction. So what happens in a situation like this?

```cpp
...
QLabel lbl("Hello world");
QWidget win;
lbl.setParent(&win);
...
```

The answer is not pretty. When these objects are destructed, `win` will be destructed first and it will call the destructor of `lbl`, unfortunatly `lbl` is an automatic object (which means deleting it manually is undefined behaviour); it will be properly destructed *after* `win` but by that time its too late. This is just one example but it highlights some of the weird bugs which can occure if you violate Qt's assumption that it manages your memory for you.

Overall the minimal overhead of dynamic memory allocation compared to automatic allocation is worth it in order to prevent hard to track down and weird bugs like the one above. IMO you should *always* let Qt manage your memory for you because thats the way it was designed and thats the way it assumes you will use it.

Comment: Thank you, its a little bit unusual listening about that heap allocation is more secure than stack allocation for memory management. But if this is the qt philosophy we must follow it.

Comment: If you don’t pass a parent, stack allocation is safe though. For cases like e.g. QFile, it’s also what I would recommend.